# Matrix whose characteristic polynomial does not splits over field.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, field-theory

I need an example of matrix which is **non-zero** and **not nilpotent** whose characteristic polynomial does **not** splits over field $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Try to find a matrix with characteristic polynomial $t^{2}+1.$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Thursday morning: if we try to diagonalize over the reals, we have **real numbers** $a,b,c,d$ with $ad-bc \neq 0,$ with
$$
\frac{1}{ad-bc}  \; \; 
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
d & -b \\
-c & a
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}
\right) =
\frac{1}{ad-bc} \; \;
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
-(ab+cd) & -(b^2 + d^2) \\
a^2 + c^2 & ab+cd
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The resulting matrix cannot be diagonal unless both $b^2 + d^2 = 0$ and $a^2 + c^2 = 0,$ meaning all four of $a,b,c,d = 0,$ with the **contradictory** outcome that $ad-bc = 0.$

With the same letters, if we now allow complex values, we can simply assign $a=d=1$ and $b=c=i$ to diagonalize over the complexes.

Comment: Sir from your example we can see, eigenvalue of matrix are $x= i$ with algebraic multiplicity 1 and $x= -i$ with algebraic multiplicity 1and algebraic multiplicity = geometric multiplicity for both $i$ and $-i$ but still given matrix is not diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$. Sir is am I correct? But why this happened?

Comment: I saw a theorem which say, a matrix is diagonalizable if and only if algebraic multiplicity of each eigenvalue is equal its to geometric multiplicity. So here in example given by you (@Will Jagy sir) this happened but still I think matrix given by you is not diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$